# Optimise threading with selenium

Tags: python, multithreading, selenium, tkinter, python-multithreading

**My Aim:**

I use a `for` loop to run multiple selenium scripts threads.
These scripts are all the same, and follow basic selenium principles

- clicking a button
- sending text to text boxes
- waiting for element to be clickable or visible
- and a usage of `time.sleep()` to mimic human behaviour.

All these scripts need to finish within a time frame of two minutes,

- e.g. I start the loop at 6:00pm all threads should be finished at 6:02pm

**Note each script takes 1 - 1.5 minutes to complete, so my question is not about increasing script time**

**My Problem:**

When I run my code it works and everything is fine, but I feel it isn't optimised as much.

For instance there's normally a blue loading circle on my mouse pointer when my threads are starting, so I know the threads are hogging the CPU.

As I'm running my selenium threads with a Tkinter GUI, I don't want the threads to cause lag or slow down the GUI.

**So finally my question is how do I optimise threading with selenium.**

---

I've created a minimal reproduced example of my original code.

```
import threading
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time


class go(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    def run(self):
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument('--headless', )
        self.browser = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe',options=options)
        self.browser.get('https://www.wikipedia.org/')

        WebDriverWait(self.browser, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "searchInput"))).send_keys('Python',Keys.ENTER)
        time.sleep(3)
        print('Moved To Next Section ')

        WebDriverWait(self.browser, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Computing"))).click()
        time.sleep(3)
        print('Moved To Next Section ')

        WebDriverWait(self.browser, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "People"))).click()
        time.sleep(3)

        print('Moved To Next Section ')
        WebDriverWait(self.browser, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Roller coasters"))).click()
        time.sleep(3)

        print('Moved To Next Section ')
        WebDriverWait(self.browser, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Vehicles"))).click()
        time.sleep(3)

        print('Moved To Next Section ')
        WebDriverWait(self.browser, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Weaponry"))).click()
        time.sleep(100)


for count in range(70):
    go().start()
```

Comment: You're starting 70 chrome processes at once, so yes, definitely expect CPU to go to 100%. Other than messing around with chrome flags there's not much to be done here.